# angular4 router-outlet name dynamically

Tags: angular, router, angular4-router

I want to realize dynamic tabs.So I need create many  and The number is uncertain.In angular2, I find this [solution](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17173) .When I use Angular4 , it doesn't work.
How can I do this?

Comment: `code <div *ngFor="let contentTab of listTabs" [ngClass]="{'active in': contentTab.isActive}" class="tab-pane fade">
      <router-outlet name='{{contentTab.outlet}}'></router-outlet>
      <!--<app-my-outlet></app-my-outlet>-->
      <!--<div appMyOutlet name="{{contentTab.outlet}}"></div>-->
    </div>`

Comment: Why would you need differently named router-outlets for a tab component with dynamic tabs?

Comment: I want to diferent content for difrent tabs.
just like this question https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17173

Comment: I get that, but you always only show a single tab, therefore you can display every tab content in the same router-outlet, even when it's different content.

Comment: As you say, I swith tabs. But when I come back to the pre tab, the content must reload. This is not a result I want.

Comment: You can implement a custom reuse-strategy, so components don't get destroyed and re-created.

Answer (score 2):

At last, I found another way with dynamical router.[Here](https://embed.plnkr.co/9L72KpobVvY14uiQjo4p/) is the example.

Comment: Here is another solution.https://juristr.com/blog/2017/07/ng2-dynamic-tab-component/